# Nortonizing the following circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Given the following circuit, I want to calculate \$ I_x, V_x \$

[image]

So I decided to transform the middle upper branch the (\$1 \Omega \$ and 2V ) into its Norton equivalent a current generator in parallel with a resistor but I ended up with two different values of \$ I_x \$. Is there a better approach? Also what's the direction of the voltage in the 3V generator? Is it pointing downward or upward?

Here are the equations I extracted from this circuit:

\$ 2I_x = V_x + i \$

And the right-most branch I don't know how to extract its LKC or LKV.

Comment: Replacing that branch with Norton equivalent should not change Ix. If it did for you, then you did something wrong..

Comment: You should show the algebra you used to get your equation.  But the equation makes no dimensional sense:  it purports to add a voltage to a current to get a current.  If you show your algebra, maybe someone can help you identify your error.  Your reference to a direction of a voltage is not appropriate.  Voltage is a potential difference.  It has a polarity, not a direction.  The polarity of the 3 V source is positive terminal down, negative terminal up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there a better approach?*

Sometimes you have to go a little off-course to find the answer. Here's my initial change (and note that \$V_x\$ is no longer valid for this new circuit): -

[image]

But, you can calculate \$V_x\$ once you have solved the modified circuit by applying the solution back to your initial circuit.

So, now you have two voltage sources in series and two resistors in series that reduce down to: -

[image]

Then I'd reduce again like this: -

[image]

Simple analysis tells us that the currents through the two vertical resistors are these: -

[image]

Can you take it from here?

---

Here's the original and one of the derived circuits in a simulator: -

[image]

The important values to take away are those boxed in orange.

Comment: great also V_x is the same voltage across the middle resistor?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI no it isn't. You have to disregard V_x until you find the values I've highlighted in the orange boxes then, apply those to your original circuit to find V_x.

Comment: i dont understand how you got the current passing through the resistors in parallel in middle

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI the current in that part of the circuit has to be 1 amp. Do you see this?

Comment: No i dont see why honestly

Comment: There is a current source that produces \$I_x - 1\$ amps <-- do you understand how that came about?

Comment: yes i know how you got that transformation of \$ I_x - 1 \$

Comment: \$I_x -1\$ is flowing towards those two resistors and, \$I_x \$ is flowing to the right away from them therefore, the current through those resistors has to be -1 amp downwards (or 1 amp upwards). Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes infinite thanks!