# Logic behind the current through these parallel resistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis

From the following circuit:

[image]

What is the logic behind the current values through the two resistors? Is it a voltage divider or Millman or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a KCL and the current divider rule.

For the upper node, we have:

$$I_X = I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} + I_X - 1$$

We can solve for \$ I_{R_1} + I_{R_2}\$

$$I_X = I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} + I_X - 1$$
$$0 = I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} - 1$$

$$I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} = 1 $$

So \$I_{R_1} = 1A * \frac{1\Omega}{1\Omega + 2\Omega} = 0.333A\$
And \$I_{R_2} = 1A - I_{R_1} = 0.666A \$

Current divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC9uD1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We have two resistors connected in parallel, Thus, the voltage seen by the resistors is the same.

From KVL we can write (1):

$$I_1 R_1 = I_2 R_2$$

And from KCL we have (2):

$$I = I_1 + I_2$$

Now we can solve for \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$

For example, from (2)  we have \$I_1 = (I - I_2)\$ and substitute this into the first one.

$$(I - I_2)R_1 = I_2R_2$$
$$IR_1 - I_2R_1 = I_2R_2$$
$$IR_1 = I_2R_2 + I_2R_1$$
$$IR_1 = I_2(R_1 + R_2)$$
$$I_2 = I \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Now we can put this into (2) - and we get:

$$I = I1 +  I \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$
$$I_1 = I -  I \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$
$$I_1 = \frac{I(R_1 + R_2) - I R_1}{R1 + R2}$$
$$I_1 = \frac{I R_1 + I R_2 - I R_1}{R1 + R2}$$
$$I_1 = \frac{I R_2}{R1 + R2}$$
$$I_1 = I\frac{ R_2}{R1 + R2}$$

Comment: Neat, you just made someone's homework. The question was not about solving it, but telling how to solve it.

Comment: no i still need to understand why they did  \$I_{R_1} = 1 A * \frac{1}{1+2}\$

Comment: @Justme The solution was already given here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/685867/nortonizing-the-following-circuit

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI  The current divider rule:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpfOH_uBKCw

Answer (score 0):

It's a **current** divider.

Yes, such a thing exists. You have to look it up. It's inside your textbook.

Comment: no i got it thanks to @G36 i was confused on how to apply KCL in such circuit, infinite thanks to them